# Declare and set works in SQL Server, but not in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
DECLARE @start_date DATETIME                  
DECLARE @end_date DATETIME             
            
SET @start_date = CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()),120) + '01 00:00:00.000'            
SET @end_date = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@start_date)
```

Comment: The code in your question is [Transact-SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL) which is not standard SQL and is proprietary to Microsoft. [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) is also not standard SQL and is proprietary to Oracle. Do you think that the code in your question can be used, as is, in an Oracle database?

Comment: The data types and functions are also not valid for Oracle SQL (or PL/SQL). Unless you have code that is ANSI SQL, and even then only the subset of ANSI SQL that both SQL Server and Oracle adhere to, you will need to translate or rewrite your code when moving between database platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Microsoft's T-SQL [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a65718e97c025e35bfcb0d3dd50744cd) and is not valid Oracle PL/SQL. The equivalent PL/SQL code would be:

```sql
DECLARE
  start_date TIMESTAMP := ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -1);
  end_date   TIMESTAMP := ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1);
BEGIN
  -- Do something
  NULL;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d6c5f37742c0ddf04ec437a328c0a6ed)*